# Adjusting position size in Joomla

Tags: html, css, joomla

Good Day...

Please take a look at my site here...
[www.compumodsa.com](http://www.compumodsa.com)
(still working on a lot of things there :P)
I am using a copy of Protostar that I am editing to what I want it to look like.

Basically I just want the mid position, witch has the FB inbedded wider and the 2 positions on the side narrower.
I have switched my template from statick to fluid and the side positions are way to wide for me.

I have gone through my template CSS and Index file but it dose not want to change.
I have looked for settings in the template but cant find any, or the correct one.

Where do i have to edit what to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the default CSS widths for the fluid layout by creating a custom CSS file as per: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/15597/120 and add some CSS to override the default settings.

Here's an example. Remember that span3 + margin + span 6 + margin + spam3 should equal 100%:

```
.row-fluid .span3 {
    width: 20% !important;
}
.row-fluid .span6 {
    width: 56% !important;
}
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    margin-left: 2%  !important;
}
.row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes but a Joomla update might overwrite your changes, hence the custom user.css.

Comment: I have a custom template, copied from Protostar that dose not update. So i will give it a try...

Comment: Yes, that would be fine.

Comment: Ok, searched for all those settings in the template.css file and changed it. Still no changes in the sizes.

Comment: You might need to clear the cache to see the changes.

Comment: Made the user.css and it is working now. Thank you very mutch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for centering this main layout:

```
<main id="content" role="main" class="span6" style="
        text-align: center;">

    </main>
```

Or you can change in css using class

```
.span6{
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Where (witch file) would I find this?

Comment: In admin panel of your site, Go to template manager then you have the template files to edit.

Comment: Thx for the centering advice.

Comment: Glad to help! Welcome..!